# CSS Box Sizing Issue

Tags: html, css, height, margins, device-width

I would really appreciate your help if you are able to solve my issue. I have created a div and turned it into a slideshow for instructions on my page. The issue with the slide show div is that it looks fine on a small screen but not on a computer screen. The size of the div is too small, so there is some overflow. Do you know how I could get it to cover all of the content, regardless of the device size?

I have tried playing with the hieght and width elements as well as the margins. I have also temporarily set the overflow to scroll.

here are some pictures to help you visualize the issue:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFQZR.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn2tK.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG4tp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post need imprrovement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try giving `height` to the picture `divs` instead of the container. You can give `paddings` to container. And try giving sizes with `percentages` instead of `px`. It should help when screen size changes. Also if you gave your whole page, `height` property , remove that and try again. This is all i can think of based on the css you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was resolved when I applied max-width properties to the images that were giving me overflow issues.